# Is there a way to show last frame in opencv-python?

Tags: python, opencv

I need to show the last frame of a video. I can calculate last frame number manually and run below code.

```
last_frame_num = duration_in_seconds * video_fps #manual entry

vs = cv2.VideoCapture('test.mp4')
vs.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, last_frame_num)

while True:
    ret, frame = vs.read()
    if ret:
        cv2.imshow('last_frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(0) == 27:
        break
vs.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The first line of code is manual entry.

Is there a way I can get the last frame number directly for any video?

Comment: you can have a running count in your while loop

Comment: You can try with `last_frame_num = vs.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT) - 1` this will give you the total amount of frames. The -1 is needed because the set uses the frame count starting in 0

Comment: @api55 It worked. Thanks. Didn't need the -1 for some reason. You can post this as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you want the last frame of a video, you can use [VideoCapture::get](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#aa6480e6972ef4c00d74814ec841a2939) with the property [CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#ggaeb8dd9c89c10a5c63c139bf7c4f5704dadadc646b31cfd2194794a3a80b8fa6c2). This will give you the amount of frames in the video. You can try to assign it to your variable like this:

```
last_frame_num = vs.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
```

In my opinion it should have a `-1` as well, since `CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES` takes a "0-based index of the frame to be decoded/captured next". However, good to see that it worked for you even without the -1.