# How to get last frame of .mp4 video

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to get the last frame of a `.mp4`. 
I've tried using `CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES` however it works for some videos and then not for others.
I've tried using msec to set the last frame and it's the same situation where it works for some but not others.

The videos are all `.mp4s` and aren't corrupt.
I understand .mp4s have trouble with using `CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES` and it is recommended to use `CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC`.

Is there a way that I get the last frame 100% every time with `opencv`.

```
# Open the video file
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_file)

# get last ms
fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
total_frames = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
total_duration_ms = int(total_frames/fps*1000)
last_frame_ms = total_duration_ms - 1  # go to the last millisecond
print(f"fps {fps} total_frames {total_frames} total_duration_ms {total_duration_ms} last_frame_ms {last_frame_ms}")

cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, last_frame_ms)
ret, last_frame = cap.read()

# # # go back a few frames since for mp4s you can't go to the exact last frame
# total_frames = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
# cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, total_frames-20) # optional
# # read current frame
# current_frame_index = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES))
# print(f"current_frame_index {current_frame_index} total_Frames {total_frames}")

# #works # Iterate until at last frame. went back 3 frames so this shouldn't take too long
# while cap.isOpened():
#     # read frame
#     ret, frame = cap.read()
#     # for debugging
#     current_frame_index = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES))
#     print(f"current_frame_index {current_frame_index}")
#     if not ret:
#         break
#     # needs to be here or else wont work
#     last_frame = frame

# Convert the frame to an image
image = Image.fromarray(last_frame)
# put into cache
last_video_frame_cache[video_file] = image

video_file_seperated, video_file_ext_seperated = os.path.splitext(video_file)
last_frame_path =  video_file_seperated + "_last_frame" + ".jpg"
# write last frame
cv2.imwrite(last_frame_path, last_frame)

# for mse
last_frame_array = np.array(image)
last_frame_grey_global = cv2.cvtColor(last_frame_array, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Release the video file
cap.release()
print("getting manually")
return image
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to show last frame in opencv-python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59924971/is-there-a-way-to-show-last-frame-in-opencv-python)

Comment: no it doesn't unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to get the last frame of a .mp4.

That is not the way without playback on fly. This is how the motion picture, special effects, `OpenCV`. That is how film editor do.

You may want to try on `Tkinter` to create editor by yourself.

The problem can be fixed.

- Comment in line 28, 30, 32. 33-35 and 37.
- Move line 44 - 51 inside while/else block.
- Comment out line 56, `#return image`

Snippet:

```
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import os
import numpy as np 
  
  
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('tor_road.mp4')


# get last ms
fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
total_frames = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
total_duration_ms = int(total_frames/2)
last_frame_ms = total_duration_ms - 1  # go to the last millisecond
print(f"fps {fps} total_frames {total_frames} total_duration_ms {total_duration_ms} last_frame_ms {last_frame_ms}")

cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, last_frame_ms)
ret, last_frame = cap.read()

# # # go back a few frames since for mp4s you can't go to the exact last frame
# total_frames = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
# cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, total_frames-20) # optional
# # read current frame
# current_frame_index = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES))
# print(f"current_frame_index {current_frame_index} total_Frames {total_frames}")

# #works # Iterate until at last frame. went back 3 frames so this shouldn't take too long
while cap.isOpened():
#     # read frame
     ret, frame = cap.read()
#     # for debugging
     current_frame_index = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES))
     print(f"current_frame_index {current_frame_index}")
     if not ret:
         break
#     # needs to be here or else wont work
     last_frame = frame

# Convert the frame to an image
     image = Image.fromarray(last_frame)
# put into cache
     #last_video_frame_cache[video_file] = image

     video_file_seperated, video_file_ext_seperated = os.path.splitext('road.avi')
     last_frame_path =  video_file_seperated + "_last_frame" + ".jpg"
    # write last frame
     cv2.imwrite(last_frame_path, last_frame)

    # for mse
     last_frame_array = np.array(image)
     last_frame_grey_global = cv2.cvtColor(last_frame_array, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Release the video file
cap.release()
print("getting manually")
#return image
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Output result:

```
current_frame_index 93
current_frame_index 94
current_frame_index 95
current_frame_index 96
current_frame_index 97
current_frame_index 98
current_frame_index 99
```